# Validate expression in Angular 1.5 with operators

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I have this expression in Angular 1.5 :

```
{{(var1/var2)*100}}
```

It show me a result but how can I validate inline if the value of var2 is 0, the result of the operation would be 0 inmediately??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ var2 ? ((var1/var2)*100) : 42.5 }}
```